# #SNMP - How to compile a MIB file using SharpSNMP?

Tags: c#, .net, snmp, mib, sharp-snmp

Trying to find a sample at http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/documentation on how to compile a MIB but the reference section is sparse. Does anyone have a simple piece of code (just a console application) that demonstrates how to compile a MIB file, access a single OID from that MIB, and perform an SNMP get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two articles for you to start.

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=600003&referringTitle=Knowledge%20Base

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=600004&referringTitle=Knowledge%20Base

**Update in 2018**

MIB document support is no longer part of the open source #SNMP Library. More information can be found [here](https://pro.sharpsnmp.com/).

Comment: Hi Lex, I understand you're the creator of #SNMP. Thank you for the reply, but I still don't see any code samples on those two pages. Is there another page that actually demonstrates MIB compilation in a single source code file or a more detailed tutorial?

Comment: http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/44e580105f66#Compiler%2fCompilerCore.cs

Comment: @pokstad did you get any success?  I figured out the Compiler and Browser by myself, but can't see how to use the .module file in my own application (a testing 'mock' of our client's agent).

Comment: This answer appears out of date after moving to https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/